# preg_match_all is matching too much

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I don't know what to add to my regular expression to make it only match the 'exact' patterns.
`#users/(.+?)/#` with this string `users/john/someweirdstuff/` will be a match.

I am getting '`john`' and not '`john/someweirdstuff`' (which is a good step in the right direction), but I don't want it to match at all. Because the string (which are supposed to be URLs) aren't the same.

So basically, what do I add behind my reg exp to make it say "there should nothing after the last slash"

Comment: You should add a bit of your code and give examples with URLs and what to match from them.

Comment: You probably just need to add `$` at the end, to match the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `$` character that matches the **end of the string**.

You should also avoid matching "any character (`.`)" and you should match "any character which is not a slash (`[^/]`). As shown in the example).

Also note I omitted the question mark (`?`), the question mark in this instance changes the character matching from greedy (match as much as possible) to lazy (match as few as possible).

Use it like so:

```
#users/([^/]+)/$#
```

Comment: So I tried after reading it in the docs. But it will still match and it will make my wildcard fetch 'john/someweirdstuff'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say "there should be nothing after the last slash", say "the string ends after the last slash", i.e. `#users/(.+)/$#`. Ommitting the question mark should also work, making the plus sign "greedy", i.e. matching as much as it can.